# Data frame with list combine to single row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Input:

| LOT | ID | VALUES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | [123,456] | [0.01,0.02] |
| DEF | [654,321] | [0.03,0.04] |

Expect out:

| LOT | ID | VALUES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [ABC,DEF] | [[123,456],[654,321]] | [[0.01,0.02],[0.03,0.04]] |

Answer (score 1):

Use `agg`

```
>>> df.agg(lambda x: [x.tolist()])

          LOT                      ID                      VALUES
0  [ABC, DEF]  [[123,456], [654,321]]  [[0.01,0.02], [0.03,0.04]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert values to numpy array, then to list and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([df.T.to_numpy().tolist()], columns=df.columns)
print (df1)
          LOT                      ID                      VALUES
0  [ABC, DEF]  [[123,456], [654,321]]  [[0.01,0.02], [0.03,0.04]]
```

Or use dictionary comprehension:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({x: [df[x].tolist()] for x in df.columns})
```